# My Linux kernel module is not receiving the correct User-space Application PID

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pid

I am developing Linux kernel module which is communicating with my user-space C application. In this module, I am creating a thread. Besides, I need to know the pid of the user space process, so I am using pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID) function.

This is my module where I am facing the problem :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/siginfo.h>    //siginfo
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>    //rcu_read_lock
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>    //find_task_by_pid_type
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> 
#include <linux/random.h> 
#include <linux/kthread.h> 

#define SIG_TEST 44    // we choose 44 as our signal number (real-time signals are in the range of 33 to 64)
#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"


char *str = BTN_FILE_PATH;
int file;

struct file *f;   // keyboard driver

// prototypage des fonctions read_in_thread & read_pid
int read_in_thread(void *data);
static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset);


static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
   return 0;
}



struct read_args {
    struct file *pfile;
    const char __user *buffer;
    size_t length;
    loff_t *offset;
};


static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer, size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
  // création de la structure des arguments
    struct read_args args ;
    args.pfile = pfile;
    args.buffer = buffer;
    args.length = length;
    args.offset = offset;

struct task_struct *thread1;
char our_thread[20];
unsigned int rand;

get_random_bytes(&rand, sizeof(rand));
rand = rand % 250;
sprintf(our_thread, "thread%u", rand);

if(thread1==NULL)
{
thread1 = kthread_create(read_in_thread,&args,our_thread);
    if((thread1))
        {
            printk(KERN_INFO "Thread is created\n");
        printk("thread name %s\n", our_thread);
// lancement du thread
            wake_up_process(thread1);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Thread is awake\n");
        }
}

else 
printk("\nTHREAD1 IS NOT NULL!!! CAN NOT CREATE THREAD!!!\n"); 

return 0;                   
}



int read_in_thread(void *data) {

/************************** récupération des arguments *******************/

    struct read_args *const args = data;

/***************************   corps de la fonction ***********************/


// init des variables 

    char mybuf[10];
    enum { MAX_BUF_SIZE = 4096 };
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t rc = 0;
    struct task_struct *t;
    struct input_event ev[64];
    int yalv;

    int ret;
    struct siginfo info;
    int pid =0; 
    size_t amount = sizeof(ev);    


// récupération de l'ID du processus appelant

/* read the value from user space */
    if(args->length > 10)
        return -EINVAL;
    copy_from_user(mybuf, args->buffer, args->length);
    sscanf(mybuf, "%d", &pid);
    printk("pid = %d\n", pid);

    // the signal 
    memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
    info.si_signo = SIG_TEST;
    info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;    // this is bit of a trickery: SI_QUEUE is normally used by sigqueue from user space,
                    // and kernel space should use SI_KERNEL. But if SI_KERNEL is used the real_time data 
                    // is not delivered to the user space signal handler function. 
    info.si_int = 260;          //real time signals may have 32 bits of data.

    rcu_read_lock();
    t = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);  //find the task_struct associated with this pid
    if(t == NULL){
        printk("no such pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();


// lecture blocquante

    rc = kernel_read(f, ev, amount, &f->f_pos);

// récupération de l'événement

    if (rc > 0) {
            for (yalv = 0; yalv < (int) (rc / sizeof(struct input_event)); yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                     //eval_keycode(ev[yalv].code);
                     info.si_int = ev[yalv].code;  

// envoie du signal vers le processus appelant avec les événements lu

                                         ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);    //send the signal
                         printk("signal was send\n");
                     if (ret < 0) {
                            printk("error sending signal\n");
                        kfree(buf);
                            return ret;
                         }              
            }
        }

                if (rc < amount) {
                    /* Didn't read the full amount, so terminate early. */
                    rc = 0;
                }

    } 

    /* Free temporary buffer. */
        kfree(buf);

return 0;
}


static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .write = write_pid,
    .read = read_pid,
    //.open = open_pid,
};



static int __init signalexample_module_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Initializing LKM");
    register_chrdev(240, "mod", &my_fops);
    file = debugfs_create_file("signalconfpid", 0200, NULL, NULL, &my_fops);
    f = filp_open(str, O_RDONLY , 0);

    return 0;
}



static void __exit signalexample_module_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(240, "mod");
    debugfs_remove(file);

}

module_init(signalexample_module_init);
module_exit(signalexample_module_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

When I run my user-space program after inserting this module, it seems for the first time to work without a problem : it prints on the console :

```
Thread is created 
thread name thread91
Thread is awake
pid = 323
```

But after I exit and when I try to re-execute my user space code again it shows to me :

```
pid = 0 
No such pid
```

I want to know why it's not working in the right way when I execute my application for multiple times ? what's wrong here ? I need some help please. Thank you.

Comment: What is the point to delete your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956373/pid-task-find-vpidpid-pidtype-pid-having-issue-in-my-linux-kernel-module) and ask the new one with the **same incorrect usage** (`copy_from_user` in kernel thread) as pointed in the comments to the previous question? Stack Overflow doesn't encourage *re-creating* a question for the purpose of "ping". Instead, we prefer to have old question to be fixed. By dropping previous conversation (in comments) you only discourage others to help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for a solution for this problem, after some researches I found that using `copy_from_user` function must be used out of the thread function. So, I move it inside `read_pid` function in my code and declared the variables which it used as global variables and I am able now to usually receive the correct PID of my user space application.

Answer (score 1):

Since the only lines you use your PID is

```c
    int pid =0;
    copy_from_user(mybuf, args->buffer, args->length);
    sscanf(mybuf, "%d", &pid);
    printk("pid = %d\n", pid);
```

It is very likely that `mybuf` is invalid at the second execution (either mybuf actually contains 0 or it is null or non-parsable as an int) thus you get an error. You should print it to check its value. The error is might be user-side

Note: Please don't take it personnally but it is your 3rd thread in two day for simple question compared to the subject (kernel programming is not simple, even for LKM). I think you should dig further befor asking. I'm pretty sure you can answer alone your questions or you **will** have trouble to develop in kernelspace. To ease this debugging process, you could use a kernel debugger [see this post for setup example](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/dev-tools/gdb-kernel-debugging.html) (as pointed up by Marco Bonelly, using a kernel debugger is only worth if you plan to develop a lot in kernelspace since its deployment can take some time). Good luck.

Comment: I would not advise the usage of a kernel debugger to a novice, even the Kernel doc discourages it. The `printk` family of functions/macros is often more than enough (and an order of magnitude simpler).

Comment: As a try, I declared an `unsigned long` variable that gets the `copy_from_user` function output to see if all bytes are copied or not. The result was that sometimes there are some bytes were not copied and some times all bytes were copied, But the pid in both cases still equal to 0

Comment: @MarcoBonelli You might be right. Using a debugger requires to be familiar with `gdb` and the setup requires a little work (using `kvm` with a debuggable kernel, possibly with `-g`, creating a script to `mnt/scp` the guest's `vmlinux` and source code, ...). In my opinion in the long term it is worth the hassle but it might not be adapted for a beginner as you said.

Comment: Yeah it could be worth the hassle if you really need it. For a novice, it's basically more complex to setup a debugging environment that to write a kernel module :P

Comment: @gaston Ok, so you have an erratic behavior. Print what is sended from the userside, what is recieved and you'll see which side is the error. IMHO the error is userside.

Comment: @MaximeB. In user application, I added a line to see if the PID is written in the buffer that its contain will be send to kernel space : `sprintf(buffer, "%i", getpid())` ...
`printf ("the buffer contains : %s\n", buffer)` and when I execute it, it shows me always the write PID : `he buffer contains : 326` But in kernel side it's always arriving equal to 0

Comment: Then check the way you send data. Again, since we don't have the full code we can't help you! You should include a **minimal reproducible example** of the whole chain.
That being said, you only have a couple of functions to review, you can do it by yourself or you should definitely stay afar from the kernel, for your own sanity.
Side note: you should put errors checkings. For instance, what happens if i give more than 10 bytes to the proc interface like `-1000000000` or `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`?

Comment: @MaximeB. After `if(args->length > 10)` I added `printk("\nInvalid argument\n");` But this message does not appear when I execute the code. Besides, after `copy_from_user(mybuf, args->buffer, args->length);` I added `printk("\nmybuf contains %s\n", mybuf);` and now sometimes it shows to me the same PID number which was sent from user-space and sometimes it does not show to me anything. The problem is in `copy_from_user` function as I guess.